# Ant design Menu.Item custom style in react

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hi everyone i learning ant design with React + typescript. i need to override some default styles in Menu.Item components. but i have a problem with remove border-right style when user click that Menu.Item using styleComponent. i don't know the exact way but i inspect that component and i picked the className from inspection and made border-right: 3px solid transparent

but still it didn't work for me Here is the code i attach below

```
import { Layout, Menu } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Flex } from "../styleComponents/commonUtilsStyles";
import {
  MenuUnfoldOutlined,
  MenuFoldOutlined,
  UserOutlined,
  VideoCameraOutlined,
  UploadOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons";
import SubMenu from "antd/lib/menu/SubMenu";

const MenuItem = styled(Menu.Item)`
  .ant-menu-vertical .ant-menu-item::after,
  .ant-menu-vertical-left .ant-menu-item::after,
  .ant-menu-vertical-right .ant-menu-item::after,
  .ant-menu-inline .ant-menu-item::after {
    border-right: 3px solid transparent !important;
  }
`;

const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

const FlexContainer = styled(Flex)`
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 32px #cccccc, -6px -6px 32px #f4f4f4;
`;

const HeaderContainer: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Sider>
          <Menu mode="inline">
            <SubMenu key="submenu" title="number">
              <MenuItem className="no-border" key="1">
                one
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem className="no-border" key="2">
                two
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem className="no-border" key="3">
                three
              </MenuItem>
            </SubMenu>
            <MenuItem className="no-border" key="11">
              one 1
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem className="no-border" key="21">
              two 1
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem className="no-border" key="31">
              three 1
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
      </Layout>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default HeaderContainer;
```

output

[image]

but i need to remove that border line style when user click that menu it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a css file and set the `border-right` property to `0px` for following classes to remove the right border.

index.css

```css
.ant-menu-vertical .ant-menu-item::after,
.ant-menu-vertical-left .ant-menu-item::after,
.ant-menu-vertical-right .ant-menu-item::after,
.ant-menu-inline .ant-menu-item::after {
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way is using Emotion React

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Menu } from "antd";
```

and then overwrite the style (you need to inspect to know the antd css class)

```
/**
 * ant-menu-item:hover::after
 * ant-menu-item-selected
 * ant-menu-item-selected:after
 */

const CustomMenu = styled(AntMenu)`
    && .ant-menu-item:hover::after {
        border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    }
    
    && .ant-menu-item-selected {
        background-color: #EEF6F7;
        border-top: 4px solid #B80012;
        border-radius: 0px;
        color: #B80012;
    }    

    && .ant-menu-item-selected:after {
        border-bottom-width: 0px;        
        border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
`;
```

Finally, use it as a component

```
return (
    <ConfigProvider theme={theme}>
        <CustomMenu
            onClick={onClick}
            selectedKeys={[current]}
            mode="horizontal"
            items={menuItems}
            {...props}
        />                
    </ConfigProvider>
);
```

This is how I test in Storybook
[Custom AntDesign Horizontal menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGRY5.png)

**EXPLAINATION**
Why can we do this?

- Firstly, Emotion styled component' **styled** can style any component as long as it accepts a **className** prop. https://emotion.sh/docs/styled
- Secondly, let's check Ant Design source code, go to Menu component, we will see index.tsx import **InternalMenu** in this line `import InternalMenu from './menu';`
- Then, we go to menu.tsx, which export **InternalMenu** component and see its props here `const InternalMenu = forwardRef<RcMenuRef, InternalMenuProps>((props, ref) => {...}`
- And scroll down, in the destructuring part it has  `const { prefixCls: customizePrefixCls, className,...restProps} = props;`

=> Here you can see it accepts **className** props, which means you can apply what styled component approach which EmotionJS offers.

Have fun!

Binh Truong :)